# pyspark filtering list from RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

i have a file  names.txt

sample data:

> hi hello hey
>
> my name is jack
>
> lets do it

and i have a list

```
remove = ['it','name']
```

i created a RDD for the names.txt , i want to filter out any element from it that match a value from the list  , the expected results a RDD with one element

> hi hello hey

My code:

```
RDD = sc.textFile("myfiles/names.txt").map(lambda x: x.split())

remove = ['it','name']

result = RDD.filter(lambda X : "remove.values" not in X)

for i in result.collect() : print i
```

i need to use some kind of iterate method,but doesn't work for me.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the builtin [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to filter out cases where any of the bad values match:

```python
result = RDD.filter(lambda X: all(val not in X for val in remove))
```